# Apex : How to set page item value containing the character "&"?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Apex page with an Item : P15_Token

I'm trying to open this page and set the item P15_Token with a value like '&Transaction123'

I'm using the following URL but it's not working. The item is empty.

I understand that the issue is coming from the character '&'. If I remove it, it works properly.

```
f?p=App:Page:Session::No::P15_Token:&Transaction123
```

I tried :

```
f?p=App:Page:Session::No::P15_Token:'&Transaction123
f?p=App:Page:Session::No::P15_Token:/&Transaction123
f?p=App:Page:Session::No::P15_Token:*&Transaction123
f?p=App:Page:Session::No::P15_Token:&&Transaction123
```

But none of them worked.

I checked the item security configuration. It's set to : **Restricted Characters : All Characters can be saved.**

Can anyone know how to set the item to something like '&xxxxx' ?

Thanks

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Try `%26` instead of `&`

```
f?p=App:Page:Session::NO:RP:P15_TOKEN:%26Transaction123
```